# Retrieving the contents of XML tags from Postgres Database

Tags: php, database, postgresql, xml-parsing

I am creating a website with a blog. I will be using a Postgres database with PHP. The blog posts will each have multiple pages. I want to save all the pages of each post in an XML data field.

To be clear, each post will have one row in the database table. Each row will have several fields, including postID, date, htmlData, etc.

The htmlData column will be the XML data field. The html data of the different pages will be stored/represented in **htmlPage** tags (see below).

Now, how do I extract/select the contents of a specific htmlPage tag as they are?

```html
<htmlPage id="1">

  <div class="pageContainer">

    <div id="pageContents">

      <h1>Introduction</h1>

      <p>

        Text here. <img src="/images/silver.png" alt="silver">

      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</htmlPage>


<htmlPage id="2">

  <div class="pageContainer">

    <div id="pageContents">

      <p>

        Text here. <img src="/images/gold.png" alt="gold">

      </p>

    </div>

  </div>

</htmlPage>
```

Comment: Please post what you tried (eg, your code), in order to achieve the expected results. SO is a site where people help you to better understand what is happening, not where people will do coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Given this example table (you'll want to give more thought to your actual table):

```
CREATE TABLE content.xmlexample
(
    content_id character varying,
    xml_content xml
)
```

Here are examples of how these records might be inserted. It's very important to note the use of the [CDATA tag](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/working-with-cdata.html) here. Enclosing your content within CDATA will prevent certain characters from breaking the XML parser:

```
INSERT INTO content.xmlexample (content_id, xml_content) VALUES ('1', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<htmlpage><![CDATA[<htmlPage id="1">
  <div class="pageContainer">
    <div id="pageContents">
      <h1>Introduction</h1>
      <p>
        Text here. <img src="/images/silver.png" alt="silver">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>]]></htmlpage>');

  INSERT INTO content.xmlexample (content_id, xml_content) VALUES ('2', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<htmlpage><![CDATA[<htmlPage id="2">
  <div class="pageContainer">
    <div id="pageContents">
      <h1>Introduction</h1>
      <p>
        Text here. <img src="/images/gold.png" alt="gold">
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>]]></htmlpage>');
```

And here are examples of selecting the data out:

```
SELECT xml_content 
FROM content.xmlexample
WHERE content_id = '1';

SELECT xml_content 
FROM content.xmlexample
WHERE content_id = '2';
```

A footnote to all this: embedding HTML within XML, in my experience, is a potentially bad idea. I'm not considering this in my answer. [Here is an article](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/08/20/embedded.html) that explains some of the perils of jamming escaped markup inside your markup.